# nginx + passenger not using rackup file

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, rack

I have an issue where Passenger is not detecting the config.ru file for the following nginx server

```
    server {
            listen 80;
    passenger_enabled on;
            server_name callumj.com cjlondon.com;
            access_log logs/callumj.access.log;
            root /webapps/callumj_com/public;
    }
```

Nginx just seems to ignore it and treat it as a normal web page (as I get forbidden areas when it tries to look for index.html in public). I have verified that the rackup command and execute config.ru and it boots up sucessfully.

I have another server directive much like this which is powered by Rails and it seems to be working perfectly.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a permissions error on root the /webapps directory.
Silly me.